# Regex look for multiples on different lines

Tags: regex

So I am trying to put some regex together that looks for 2 instances of a national insurance number. But it needs to find the NIN regardless of its placement so it doesn't matter if there are other words in between or on new lines.

```js
((\W|^)([a-zA-Z]{2}(|\s|\W))([0-9]{2}(|\s|\W)){3}([a-zA-Z]{1})(.*)){2,}
```

This is as close as i've got however this only works when on the same line it doesn't work if the NIN is on a different line

Comment: `.` does not match line break chars by default. Use the workaround, `[\w\W]`, or the appropriate DOTALL modifier.

Comment: Why not parse the file line by line?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, if there is text on the new line before the NIN it doesn't match, example:
ND111111D jnjkjnkjn
dfsdf ND111111D 
ND111111D jnjkjnkjn
ffdsfds ND111111D
doesn't throw a match